# Interprocess communication from Webaddin to c++ application

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins

I need to create web addins for Excel, Word, Powerpoint, Outlook and send data to C++ desktop application.

Data's like:

1. Current cell selected in Excel
2. Current sheet Name
3. Selected text in current word document
4. Current file name of Excel, Word, Powerpoint

First I tried using vsto add-in and I am able to send and receive above data from Office applications to C++ application using Named Pipe.

Now I want to achieve the same thing using Web addin. It uses Javascript, how to acheive interprocess communication in Webaddin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web add-in sandbox does not allow for direct interprocess communication for security reasons. You may create a RESTful service that the web add-in can send data to, and request the data from the C++ application.